# HDFView 2.4 make portable

Tags: java, hdf5

i try to download and install HDFView 2.4 from [here](http://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/hdf-java/current/bin/HDFView-2.14-win_64.zip)and it work but i need to use on another computer whithout admin pass then i need portable version

when i run the hdfview.bat file the app run but can't read any .h5 file data also the included samples file

i read somewhere to install Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable there's any way to put the corrected dll, exe avalible without install C++ 2015 Redistributable .exe

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved !!**

Hi at all i have find the missing file is vcruntime140.dll "Microsoft C Runtime Library" you can copy on the directoy where HDFView 2.4 is installed like :HDFView\2.14.0\ and it run correctyl hdf5 format

By by